# Extract Words from a file

Tags: python

I open a file using python to find whether a predefined set of words are present in the opened file or not. I took the predefined set of words in a list and opened the file that has to be tested. Now is there any method to extract words in python rather than lines. Thats makes my work lot easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import re

def get_words_from_string(s):
    return set(re.findall(re.compile('\w+'), s.lower()))

def get_words_from_file(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as inf:
        return get_words_from_string(inf.read())

def all_words(needle, haystack):
    return set(needle).issubset(set(haystack))

def any_words(needle, haystack):
    return set(needle).intersection(set(haystack))

search_words = get_words_from_string("This is my test")
find_in = get_words_from_string("If this were my test, I is passing")

print any_words(search_words, find_in)

print all_words(search_words, find_in)
```

returns

```
set(['this', 'test', 'is', 'my'])
True
```

Comment: a perfect solution...but what if the file is too large..any smarter solution

Comment: (shrug) sure, parse the file line by line, accumulating the word-set as you go.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a few things

- Call file.readlines() and split the entire text on your desired delimiter if your text isn't large
- Call read() and do it bytes at a time

Check out the pydocs for file - http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/bltin-file-objects.html

Answer (score 1):

This code will show what words are present in the file, given that the word exactly matches, and is not preceded or followed by punctuation or other characters, and is of the same case.  With some minor adjustment, the code could be made more forgiving.

```
words = set(['hello', 'world', 'testing'])
f     = open('testfile.txt', 'rb')
data  = set(f.read().split())
print words.intersection(data)
```