# reading words from a file into a set, maintaining order

Tags: python

here is an array of Unicode words used in the python script.

```
texts =[u"abc", u"pqr", u"mnp"]
```

The script is working as expected with the above 3 words example. The issue is that there are thousands of words in a text file. 
How do I read from the text file?

**Update:**
I have 2 issues. The sequence of words from the text file is not maintained in the output.
The text file has unicode characters and hence the "u" in my original example.

```
# cat testfile.txt
Testing this file with Python

# cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

f     = open('testfile.txt', 'r')
texts  = set(f.read().split())
print (texts)

# python test.py
set(['this', 'Python', 'Testing', 'with', 'file'])
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963499/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no problem with your file reading code. Given that the words appear in the file separated by whitespace, and the file is not too big to be gulped with a single `read`, it should work just fine. The real problem is the order of the words if you shove them into a `set`.

If you need the words in the same order as they appear in the file, why are you using a `set`? Just keep them in a list.

If you need a `set` to remove duplicates and/or other purposes, then you have the following options:

- Use the `OrderedDict` class - standard in Python since 2.7, and recipes exist online for earlier versions.
- Create an ordered set - here's a [SO question with a good discussion of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)

Comment: >> why are you using a set? Just keep them in a list. # good question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is because how sets work. They don't maintain the order of the items stored in the set.

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set):

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects