# How to create a word list made up of the words from file

Tags: python, readfile

I am creating a function for a words game and I need to create a word list made up of the words from a file called wordlist.txt. My first thought was to open that file firstly and pass the open file as an argument to the function Im am trying to create. But lastly I realized that my funtion it supossed to return a list of all words with the newlines removed from the open file words_file.(It is that can even possible in python?). On the others each line Each line of the file contains a word in uppercase characters from the standard English alphabet but this I think I got it by using upper() and.split().
I am terrily stuck it in this. Any help will be useful. Thank you so much in advance.
PS: I found this structure looking for any information about this kind of read file. words_file = askopenfile(mode='r', title='Select word list file') Coul be useful in this case anyway?

This is my function structure:

```
def read_words(words_file):

    """ (file open for reading) -> list of str

    Return a list of all words (with newlines removed) from open file
    words_file.

    Precondition: Each line of the file contains a word in uppercase characters
    from the standard English alphabet.
    """
    file = open("C:\Python34\wordlist.txt", "r")
    return words_file.read(wordlilst.txt).replace("\n", "").upper().split()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check whether a file exists using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python)

Comment: Sorry but I think have nothing to do with that question

Comment: `askopenfile` is from `tkinter`. It can be usefull if you create program with GUI. It allow you select filename in window.

Comment: what is a problem ? show FULL error message in QUESTION.

Comment: if you replace `'\n'` with `''` then you can get one long word which you can't split.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract Words from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963499/extract-words-from-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to use the parameter `words_file` as the source of your file. Your code ignores it, assigns a hardcoded file to `file`, then tries to call `read` on the non-existing parameter.
I think this might be what you wanted:

```
def read_words(words_file):
words_list = [] # initialize empty word list
with open(words_file) as file: # open the file specified in parameter
                               # 'with' makes sure to close it again
    for line in file:          # iterate over lines
        words_list.append(line.replace("\n", "")) # add every line to list
                                 # ^ remove trailing newline, which iterating includes
return words_list # return completed list
```

To run it for your file, use `read_words("C:\Python34\wordlist.txt")`, which will return the list.